# How do I find all windows classes that were created by a program that was started via CreateProcess in win32 API programming?

Tags: winapi, createprocess

I'm launching a program through `CreateProcess` and this program creates many different windows classes. For example, one of the classes is called `Message_Dispatch`. Another one is called `Main_App_Frame`. There are several more.

How do I enumerate all windows classes belonging to the process started by `CreateProcess` API call?

Comment: If you can explain why you need this information, maybe somebody can solve your underlying problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. If you need this information from the process you launched, you'll have to set up a custom interface between the processes to communicate this information. There isn't much you can do with another process's classes without that process's cooperation anyway.

Comment: Hi Raymond. Thanks for the answer. It looks like you actually can do it indirectly (see Remy's answer) by enumerating all windows, then using `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` to compare each window with the process ID that `CreateProcess()` returns, then you can use `GetClassName()` for each matching window you find. What do you think about this? It looks like it works.

Comment: That doesn't enumerate all the registered classes. That only enumerates the classes which are currently being used by a window. You aren't seeing the classes that were registered but haven't yet created a window. But it's still not clear why you need those classes, since you can't do anything with them.

Answer (score 1):

You can't enumerate the registered window classes directly, but you can enumerate the currently active windows That are running at any given moment, via `FindWindow/Ex()`, `EnumWindows()`, `EnumChildWindows()`, etc.  You can use `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` to compare each window with the process ID that `CreateProcess()` returns, then you can use `GetClassName()` for each matching window you find.